# textfield value Edit and scroll table view textfield show previous old value

Tags: swift

set the value form json on custom cell and change cell value and scroll tableview top to bottom textfield value show previous value. i have use 5sections on table view

I tried model class

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"SetSupscriptionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SetSupscriptionViewCell
cell.txtMonthlyPrice.tag = indexPath.row
txtMonthlyPrice = cell.txtMonthlyPrice
cell.setDataInCell(dict: dictFanSetting)
```

---

custom cell:

```
func setDataInCell(dict: NSDictionary) {

    print("in cell: ",dict)
    let strAmount = String(format: "%@", arguments:[dict.object(forKey: "monthly_subscription") as! CVarArg])

    let str = String(format: "$ %.2f" , Float(strAmount) ?? 00.00)

    txtMonthlyPrice.text = str
}
```

Comment: Hi, unrelated to your question but I see you are using a lot of old remnants from Obj-C days in Swift. Look into how to use native Swift types such as `Dictionary` and Swift string interpolation. It'll make your life much more easier and your code much more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In the `SetSupscriptionViewCell` class, override the `prepareForReuse()` method and set the `txtMonthlyPrice` (and any other labels, imageviews, textfields etc) to `nil`. It essentially resets the values of those controls before the cell is reused.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    txtMonthlyPrice.text = nil
}
```